# Tables in one of my schemas are not listed in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. What can be the reason?

Tags: sql-server, schema, information-schema

I have three schemas in my SQL Server database, but when I query over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` only tables that belong to two of the schemas are listed. Tables in the third schema are not listed. What can be the cause?

My query is:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

I think it is a permissions issue, but I can't find it. I have compared the schemas (and their owner roles) and their permissions look the same. I can't find any difference between them.

I want to list all the tables, not schemata. Even when I run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` my third schema is not in the result.

When I run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('Schema3.Table1')` I receive `NULL` whereas the result for `SELECT OBJECT_ID(Schema2.Table1)`is the `object_id`.

Comment: Does the third schema show up when querying sys.objects?  From this link: - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx - ** Important ** Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of an object is to query the sys.objects catalog view. INFORMATION_SCHEMA views could be incomplete since they are not updated for all new features.

Comment: A likely cause is permissions.  You must have been granted some permission on an object for meta-data to be visible.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx.

Comment: What happens if you run `select s.name from sys.schemas s;` ? Do you see three schemas?  Also try, `select s.name, count(t.object_id) from sys.schemas s left join sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id group by s.name;` which will give you the count of tables for each schema.

Comment: @MaxVernon Both your queries works as it should be, the first one shows the third schema as well as other two, and when I run second query number of tables in third schema is correct. I don't know what is the reason that INFORMATION_SCHEMA does not show the third schema. But I can change my query that it uses sys schema instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand has an excellent post here about why you shouldn't trust the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views - [unreliable information_schema schema information on SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217886/unreliable-information-schema-schema-information-on-sql-server)

To summerize:

> 1). The wording in the documentation is not accurate, and it is in the
>   process of being corrected (see Connect #686118). I'm not sure if they
>   will correct the 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 docs all at once, or whether
>   the older versions will even get updated. The point is that I can not
>   envision a case where the schema in either view is incorrect, but even
>   more so, that info_schema is incorrect while sys.objects is correct.
>   The latter is impossible - the info_schema view is based entirely on
>   the sys.objects view (just look at SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID
>   ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'));), so if one is incorrect, they're both
>   incorrect. There are probably obscure cases where they can both be
>   incorrect, but not in current versions (for example, in SQL Server
>   2000, with the config option allow updates enabled, delete from
>   sysusers a user who owns an object - not really relevant or possible
>   today, and not something I'm willing to try, but it's the only one I
>   can imagine would have motivated the current wording at any point in
>   time).
>
> 2). In general, INFORMATION_SCHEMA views should be avoided in favor of
>   the catalog views introduced in SQL Server 2005 (and augmented since
>   then). Why? Because the catalog views continue being developed as new
>   features are added to SQL Server, while the info_schema views have
>   not. As I mentioned in my comment, try to find information about
>   filtered indexes in info_schema. Same goes for included columns, XML
>   indexes, identity/computed columns, foreign keys against unique
>   indexes - these are all either missing entirely or represented
>   differently in the info_schema views. In Denali they added an
>   info_schema view for Sequences but again this meets the bare minimum
>   of the standard and doesn't include any information about SQL
>   Server-specific implementation details (for example, whether it's
>   exhausted, and if they add any new features in the future you can be
>   sure the info_schema view will not be kept in the loop). The only case
>   where you would stick to info_schema views is if (a) you are writing
>   metadata routines that need to work across info_schema-compliant
>   platforms AND (b) you aren't using any platform-specific features that
>   will be missed. Aside from multi-platform vendor tools this is
>   probably a pretty rare scenario (and even in that case may lead to
>   displeased customers who are using those features and the tool didn't
>   pick them up).
>
> 3). I filed a separate Connect suggestion (Connect #686121) that they
>   plaster a warning about this incompleteness on all INFORMATION_SCHEMA
>   view topics in Books Online. I don't think it's very well known that
>   they are not the preferred way to get metadata out of SQL Server, and
>   who could blame folks for not seeing this - after all, we're always
>   told that using standards-compliant methods is a "best practice" and
>   using proprietary methods are the opposite. As with a lot of database
>   things, "it depends" - but I suspect, more often than not, you're
>   better off using the sys catalog views unless you're in that rare
>   scenario where you're using only the features in SQL Server that are
>   common to the standard. I don't think I've come across a single
>   instance in any capacity where this was the case, but I'm more than
>   happy to learn of them if they do exist.

Comment: Thank you Scott, your answer and the link was really helpful, even in my case it should be some permission related issue. When I run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('Schema3.Table1')` I receive `NULL`whereease the result for `SELECT OBJECT_ID(Schema2.Table1)`is the object_id.